How long should I boil a liquid mixture containing vanilla extract to vaporize the alcohol, when making ice cream?
I am trying to make ice cream using an ice cream maker. I initially used a vanilla extract but didn't boil the liquid mixture. The mixture didn't freeze properly in the ice cream maker. The vanilla extract has 33% alcohol in it. I'm guessing the presence of alcohol didn't allow the mixture to freeze properly - the instruction manual that came with the ice cream maker also says that adding alcohol will interfere with the freezing process. I later tried the same procedure without the vanilla extract and I noticed the mixture froze better in the ice cream maker. I am now thinking of boiling the mixture after adding the vanilla extract. How long do you think I should boil the mixture to vaporize sufficient amount of alcohol so that it freezes well in the ice cream maker?

I don't know how your manual was worded exactly, but adding alcohol usually changes the freezing in desirable ways, making for smaller crystals, and an end product which doesn't freeze too hard. There are even alcohol-based ice creams - try a campari and pink grapefruit sorbet sometime. But that's theoretical in your case, since John Doe's answer is the right one, a teaspoon of vanilla extract is too little alcohol to make a difference.

"Cooking off alcohol" is, to a large degree, a myth. It does have a lower boiling point than water and will preferentially boil off, but it takes a long time (approximately an hour to get rid of 75%, 2 to get to 90%) https://www.isu.edu/news/2019-fall/no-worries-the-alcohol-burns-off-during-cookingbut-does-it-really.html

If you could efficiently "boil off" alcohol, moonshiiners wouldn't run thumpers on their pot stills.

Note also that high temperatures will destroy many of the volatile molecules present in pure vanilla extract, leaving you with vanillin and a few others. But you can just buy vanillin ("artificial vanilla flavor") directly, and it's even cheaper than the "real" stuff.

If you are cooking the ice cream base, like for a custard, I would recommend adding the vanilla extract after the base has cooled to keep the precious vanilla flavors.

You are talking a TINY amount of alcohol, it is very unlikely it would work as antifreeze?

I doubt the amount of vanilla extract (something like 1 teaspoon/5 ml to 2-3 cups/440-700 ml of cream and milk) and the alcohol within are sufficient to lower the freezing point by an appreciable amount.
Depending on what type of ice cream maker you're using, maybe it simply wasn't cold enough, as the cheaper ones that seem to be common in normal households use a lower part that goes in the freezer overnight.
This Seriouseats recipe for vanilla ice cream does however simmer (not boil) the ice cream base for some time, but this has nothing to do with cooking off the alcohol and more with cooking the custard.

also boiling might ruin the flavor or the texture of the custard

Yeah, this is the right answer. Lets assume 10 ml of 33% ethanol (=3.3 ml pure ethanol) in 440 ml = 0.75% ethanol. Engineering toolbox gives -4 C for 10% (v/v) ethanol, so -0.4 C for 1% or -0.3 for 0.75% (more or less, it's not quite a straight line relationship). +/-0.4 C is well within tolerance for most domestic freezing mechanisms.

When I had an ice cream maker like that, it was crucial to chill the mix as much as possible before using it. So overnight the bowl went in the freezer, and the mixed ingredients against the back of the fridge. Then when actually mixing, the lower part needed extra insulation for it to work well and to reduce the condensation that formed.

I wouldn't say "I doubt".  I would say that the amount of vanilla extract in any reasonable ice cream will surely have no significant affect on the freezing temperature.

The answer from John Doe is right.  I would add that you don't want to boil off the alcohol or the vanilla flavors.
Next time, measure the temperature of the ice cream when you're freezing/churning it.  Ice cream freezes around 22 to 25 °F, depending on its composition.  I prefer to bring mine down to 20 °F or less before I remove it from the machine.  It helps a lot to get your coolant quite a bit colder than most refrigerator/freezer combos get; down to -10 °F or so instead of 0 °F.

Yeah, unless you're making that vanilla extract meme cake (https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/vanilla-extract), the amount of alcohol it adds is simply not significant enough to affect the temperature that things happen at.
